# AngularJS: Directive can not find dependency injected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-module

Here is my plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/uqSB1gIz6XEmJfC8zHNb?p=preview

I am trying to inject [Angular Strap](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap)

The `index.html` is including the right dependencies and in correct order

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@2.3.2" data-semver="2.3.2" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-strap@0.6.6" data-semver="0.6.6" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/0.6.6/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
```

My console says

```
Error: Unknown provider: $strap.directivesProvider <- $strap.directives <- notificationDirective
@http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:29
c@http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:27
@http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:30
c@http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:27
d@http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:27
@http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:37
forEach@[native code]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module dependency for AngularStrap is listed in the wrong place.  `'$strap-directives'`  is a module dependency, not a service dependency, so it needs to be listed during the app bootstrap like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['$strap.directives']);
```

It also needs to be removed as a service DI in your directive:

```
app.directive('notification', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<div>Test</div>'
    }
});
```

This is the way they configure the Plunkers on the [AngularStrap site](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

`$strap.directives` is a module. You need to define it as a dependency for your own module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['$strap.directives']);
```

You need not inject this into the directive. Thus your directive will only look like:

```
app.directive('notification', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<div>Test</div>'
  }
});
```

Comment: This will throw an error because the directive tries to inject `strap` unsuccessfully